# How do I enable downloads from webview ios/xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, webview

I created a webview with xcode. The webapp has some pdf files for downloads that are not being downloaded to my iphone. My code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = URL(string: "http://app.site.com")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        //webView.delegate = self
        webView.load(request)
    }
}
```

How do I enable downloads?

Comment: What do you see?

Comment: when trying to download any webapp file, nothing happens.